# flutter migration to null-safety - how fix "Bad state: Error: package has unmigrated dependencies"?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety

I have a pretty big Flutter project, I'm currently adding null-safety support. My project consists of several parts - the "core" and  "client".
"Client" used "core"

```
environment:
   sdk: ">=2.10.0 <3.0.0"
..... 
 app_core:
   path: ../core
```

First I updated the core with command

```
dart migrate
```

Now I when run "dart migrate"(in core) - I get this result:

```
 All sources appear to be already migrated.  Nothing to do.
```

Now I try to update the "client" part, I run the following commands

```
dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety

[✗] indicates versions without null safety support.
[✓] indicates versions opting in to null safety.

All your dependencies declare support for null-safety.
```

Next step:

```
dart pub upgrade --null-safety
Changed 1 dependency!
1 package is discontinued.
24 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `dart pub outdated` for more information.

No changes to pubspec.yaml!
```

Next step:

```
dart pub get
```

When I run

```
dart migrate
```

I get these messages:

```
Bad state: Error: package has unmigrated dependencies.

Before migrating your package, we recommend ensuring that every library it
(either directly or indirectly) has been migrated to null safety, so
that you will be able to run your unit tests in sound null checking mode.  You
are currently importing the following non-null-safe libraries:
...//file list
..............
Please upgrade the packages containing these libraries to null 
safe versions
before continuing.  To see what null safe package versions are 
available, run
the following command: `dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety`.

To skip this check and try to migrate anyway, re-run with the 
flag
`--skip-import-check`.
```

"file list" - is a large list of files from  "client" (I did not find any regularity in it). Also, these files have no errors.

What is the reason for these warnings?
How can I fix it? Any advice - I will be grateful.

Comment: backup your code, then run 'dart migrate --skip-import-check'

Comment: then run your application, check if everything is okay